# Task not serializable - foreach function spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a function **getS3Object** to get a json object stored in S3

```
def getS3Object (s3ObjectName) : Unit = {
  val bucketName = "xyz"
  val object_to_write = s3client.getObject(bucketName, s3ObjectName)
  val file = new File(filename)
  fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)
  bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)
  bw.write(object_to_write)
  bw.close()
  fileWriter.close()

}
```

My dataframe (df) contains one column where each row is the S3ObjectName

| S3ObjectName |
| --- |
| a1.json |
| b2.json |
| c3.json |
| d4.json |
| e5.json |

When I execute the below logic I get an error saying "task is not serializable"

Method 1:-    `df.foreach(x => getS3Object(x.getString(0))`

I tried converting the df to rdd but still get the same error

Method 2:-    `df.rdd.foreach(x => getS3Object(x.getString(0))`

However it works with collect()

Method 3:-    `df.collect.foreach(x => getS3Object(x.getString(0))`

I do not wish to use the collect() method as all the elements of the dataframe are collected to the driver and potentially result in *OutOfMemory* error.

Is there a way to make the foreach() function work using Method 1?

Comment: This function `getS3Object` can not be serialized, as it is using the `s3Client` which owns an open network connection. All functions given to `map`, `foreach` etc must be serializable. In these functions, you can not use anything which "talks" to outside of your jvm process. Implement your `getS3Object` in such a way that it can be serialized.

Comment: Please first read the documentation, there are plenty of "Not serializable" occurence around the web about Spark.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for your `s3Client` can be solved as following. But you have to remember that these functions run on executor nodes (other machines), so your whole `val file = new File(filename)` thing is probably not going to work here.

You can put your `files` on some distibuted file system like HDFS or S3.

```
object S3ClientWrapper extends Serializable {
  // s3Client must be created here.
  val s3Client = {
    val awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_key_id")

    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                        .build()
  }
}

def getS3Object (s3ObjectName) : Unit = {
  val bucketName = "xyz"
  val object_to_write = S3ClientWrapper.s3Client.getObject(bucketName, s3ObjectName)
  // now you have to solve your file problem
}
```

Comment: i see what you are doing but its important that i write the s3object content to azure data lake and that is when i get the error: "Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter"

Comment: And this is how you solve that error. Functions passed to `map`, `foreach` etc must be serializable.